# no ReserveMatch found for seemingly correct path converter

Tags: html, django

I have the following anchor in my HTML template

```
<a href = "{% url 'app:pages:experiments_tables_foreign_key' data.0 col.1 col.2 col.3 %}"> {{col.1}} </a>
```

and the following line within urls.py

```
path('experiments/<str:table_name>/<uuid:foreign_key>/<str:foreign_attribute>/str:foreign_table_name>/',     ExpViews.show_foreign_key,                 name='experiments_tables_foreign_key')
```

show_foreign_key exists in views.py and is a function that I'd like to use for a view. It accepts 4 parameters.

I have the correct namespace done aswell. I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'experiments_tables_foreign_key' with arguments '('test_2', UUID('7a4c1cb5-6a7c-4fd3-8eea-8e9bef41802d'), 'ID', 'test_1')' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a typo on the url.

```
path('experiments/<str:table_name>/<uuid:foreign_key>/<str:foreign_attribute>/str:foreign_table_name>/', ExpViews.show_foreign_key, name='experiments_tables_foreign_key')
                                                                              ^^^ # lacks a <
```

So, change this to:

```
path('experiments/<str:table_name>/<uuid:foreign_key>/<str:foreign_attribute>/<str:foreign_table_name>/', ExpViews.show_foreign_key, name='experiments_tables_foreign_key')
```